# How does a new IoT device (ip camera, vacuum robot, etc.) gets accessed remotely without router firewall configuration?

Tags: router, firewall, ip-camera, iot

Typically a router firewall does not allow WAN input or forward in general.

But when we install new IP cameras or smart home devices, we can get access to them remotely (typically over 4G or LTE network) without ever re-configuring the home router's firewall.

So my question is how these devices bypass the firewall? Do they automatically ask for a port forwarding rule or do they use a completely different way to be accessed remotely?

Very confused, still learning, thanks!

Comment: Hi, you have answered your own question. If the device is not on the same network as a firewall, the firewall does not matte to that device.

Comment: So you are saying there is a separate protocol to route traffic that circumvent firewall? What is this protocol?

Comment: OK, sort of answered from here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/145945/how-can-iot-and-other-network-devices-access-the-internet-if-my-router-works-as